# Including CSS File in my Plone add-on

Tags: plone

I want to add a simple stylesheet to a plone 4 product. Therfore I added

```
<browser:resourceDirectory
    name="groovecubes.portlet.gallery.css"
    directory="css"
    />
```

to [product dir]/browser/configure.zcml, which should me enable to browse stylesheets in this folder with this syntax: ++resource++groovecubes.portlet.gallery.css/mycss.css. But it doesn't. Not even after a buildout.

Every declaration in [product dir]/profiles/default/cssregistry.xml are therefore not found. What am I missing? Is it the package name?

The packages main configure.zcml contains the line

```
 <include package=".browser" />
```

which should execute browser/configure.zcml

But is does not. I pasted the packages [configure.zcml](http://pastie.org/4702334) and [browser/configure.zcml](http://pastie.org/4702346)

Update II:

It gets even weirder. When I modifiy the head of `browser/configure.zcml` the file is recognized as malformed when I try to start the instance. But when I modify the relevant entry, startup continues normal.

Update III:

I've tested various things now, but what I found out, is that any malformed tags in `.zcml` files is ignored by the SaxParser. In every product on my dev and productive instance (Plone 4.2  / Plone 4.1). Is that maybe a new feature, I may have missed?

Update IV:

**Solved:** I removed the interface declaration from `browser/configure.zcml` that accidently used the same name. That made my .css available. But I'm still wondering about the described parser behaviour.

Comment: That should work as long as mycss.css is in the css directory...

Comment: Looks good.  Double check that the zcml is really loaded.  The best way to do that, is to deliberately make an error, for example by removing the closing '/>' and restarting the instance.  Also, since you are developing, make sure you run the instance in debug mode by starting it with 'bin/instance fg'.  A normal start may swallow some errors.

Comment: Just to make sure: the css-dir is located in browser? An __init__.py files exists in browser? (Underscores seem to be filtered here, init.py with underscores...)

Comment: @IdaEbkes: underscores mean __bolding__; use backticks (\`) to make signify a piece of code, or filename: `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the name `groovecubes.portlet.gallery.css` but try to access it as `++resource++groovecubes.portlet.gallery` instead (note the missing `.css` there).

Either use `++resource++groovecubes.portlet.gallery.css/mycss.css` or remove the `.css` part from the `resourceDirectory` registration.

If that was just a typo, check that the ZCML file is actually being loaded; the registration itself is fine if the names match.

Comment: This was just a typo in the question. Sorry, I corrected that, but it is not what causes the problem.